# Send ID with DOMNodeList

Tags: php, xpath

I have this splendid code

```
public static function city($city)
{

    $html = file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/?=$city");

    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

    $doc = new \DOMDocument();

    if($doc->loadHTML($html))
    {
        $result = new \DOMDocument();

        $xpath = new \DOMXPath($doc);

        $movies = $xpath->query("/html/body");

        $url = $xpath->query("/html/body/a/@");

        return $movies;
    }
}
```

This function returns as expected a list om movies, and i fetch them with `$movies->nodeValue`

But i want to send an ID as well.

So i try to add this snipp (to explode the ID from the URL):

```
foreach($url as $MovieId){
    $data=parse_url($MovieId->nodeValue, PHP_URL_QUERY);
    $splittedstring=explode("&",$data); 
    $id[] = substr(strstr($splittedstring[0], "="),1);
}
```

**And this works perfect when i just echo it like this:**

```
$i=0;
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($movies as $key => $movie) {
    echo '<li><a href="'.$id[$i].'">'.$movie->nodeValue . '</a></li>';
    $i++;
}
echo '</ul>';
```

**But** when trying to send it from the Model, to the view with:

```
$data = new stdClass;
$data->movie_title = $movies;
$data->movie_id = $id;

return $data;
```

I get: `Notice: Undefined property: DOMNodeList::$nodeValue`...

**My question:** How can i either

1. convert the $movies to a stdClass
2. send the id with the object(DOMNodeList) (and retrieve it how?)

Comment: Show more complete code for when you try to send it from the model to the view.

Comment: `$movies` is a node list, not a single node, which is why it worked inside a `foreach`. Do you want to store multiple movies in `$data`, or only one of them?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I want to store multiple movies in `$data->movie_titels`, so I can fetch and foreach them in a view. Togheter with ID´s

Comment: So you need `$data` to be an array of objects?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski `$data->movie_id` works fine, i can't wrap my head around why `$data->movie_title` won't. preferably both `$data->movie_title` and `$data->movie_id` as stdClass

Comment: It would help also if you would post a sample cut from the original file `http://www.example.com/?=$city`

Comment: `$data->movie_id` works because `$id` is a plain array. When you do that, you are assigning the whole array of ids onto `$data->movie_id`, not a single value as I think you intended to do. It isn't an error, but probably isn't right either.

Comment: I want so assign the whole array, i want to create a list in the view, with the movie_title and the ID

Comment: If you edit to include a sample of `http://www.example.com/?=$city` it will be clearer what the DOM relationship between the ids and titles is to be (besides just their relative positions, as your current code would handle)